# How to put NIC into promiscuous mode?

Tags: security, windows-7, networking, network-programming, sniffing

Hi
I want to put my NIC into promiscuous mode. Why? 
Because I wrote app which is able potentially to detect sniffing in my local network (send modyfied appropriately ethernet packets). I just want now check it out, so in my second comp I want to set up promisc mode. 
There's Windows 7 and simply Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card...if it makes a difference.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I`ve used [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for this sort of thing in the past

Comment: I misinterpreted the question, wireshark is the way to go

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but sth is wrong. I've checked options "Capture packets in promiscuous mode" on laptop and then I send from PC  modified ICMP Request (to correct IP but incorrect MAC address). This is one of the methods of detection sniffing in local network. As far as I know if NIC is in promisc mode it should send ICMP Reply. But there's no reply. Any ideas?

Comment: IP is a layer above MAC (see layer 3 and 2 of OSI model, respectively) - in the end, if you have the wrong MAC, the data link layer will not pass it up to the network layer.  ICMP is at the network layer, so it never received your ICMP request.

Comment: No, I're wrong. You're talking about "normally" situation, but if NIC is in promisc mode it should send answer. Read about Ping test e.g http://www.napolifirewall.com/Sniffers.htm or http://www.linux-sec.net/Sniffer.Detectors/snifferdetection.pdf But if so, then I don't know why I don't get this answer on my PC

Comment: I don't know why, wireshark works on my PC but not on notebook. If notebook is listning and sending request - PC is answering, but vice versa don't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You might not be able to put that adapter into promiscuous mode.  This is Windows, and the adapter is a Wi-Fi adapter, and, according to [this Microsoft documentation on 802.11 drivers on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), "It is only valid for the miniport driver to enable the NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_PROMISCUOUS, NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_802_11_PROMISCUOUS_MGMT, or NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_802_11_PROMISCUOUS_CTRL packet filters if the driver is operating in Network Monitor (NetMon) or Extensible Access Point (AP) modes."

If your application uses WinPcap (as does, for example, Wireshark), it can't put the driver into "network monitor" mode, as WinPcap currently doesn't support that (because its kernel driver doesn't support version 6 of the NDIS interface for network drivers), so drivers that follow Microsoft's recommendations won't allow you to put the interface into promiscuous mode.

And if it *could* put it into monitor mode, that might disable transmitting packets; according to [this Microsoft page on monitor mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), "While in NetMon mode, the miniport driver can only receive packets based on the current packet filter settings. The driver cannot send packets either on its own or through a call to its *MiniportSendNetBufferLists* function."